# find value in comma separated list for each record of a different table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

We have a table that holds our customers, the product they have and the cities they subscribe to.  The cities field is a comma separated list of numbers.

They want a stored procedure that will find all the customers that have the specific city ids they pass in, but they want to be able to pass in more than one city id.

Example
They want to find all customers that are subscribed to 22 and/or 900 (both are separate cities).

I need all customers that have one or the other or both of these cities in their comma separated list.

So I need a way to search that list for the first value and then search the list for the second value.  I was thinking of using a recursive CTE but I need to join the City table (temp table I created to separate the list of city ids they pass) and I cant.

When they put the city_ids in, I separate that list into a table that has each city id as it's own record in the temporary table.  Help?

And please don't say stop storing comma separated lists... I can't change that part of how our system functions and that is not helpful. (I've seen it many times while searching for an answer to this question).

```
Customer    |Product_ID     |Cities
6           | 49            |ALL
9           | 2760          |ALL                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
9           | 3618          |ALL                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
9           | 3981          |ALL                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
10          | 2760          |ALL                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
10          | 3618          |ALL                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
10          | 3981          |ALL
11          | 3981          |ALL
12          | 3981          |ALL
20          | 2894          |10,12,14,16,18,20,22,26,32,085,615,34,38,39,46,620,50,60,65,365,70,73,680,375,405,77,80,90,435,705
91          | 501           |510,515,520,521,522,523,525,526,527,530,535,540,542,545,550,553,555,560,563,565,566,567,569,570,571,572,573,574,575,20,22,576,580,581,582,585,587,590,591,593,595,598,600,610,612,614,615,617,618,619,620,621,623,625
```

I would be searching through something like above, looking for 20 or 900 and this is a very small sample.  The ALL is easy, I know what to do there.  It's searching through the lists that is the issue when trying to look for more than one city id.  I've been able to do it while looking for only one, it's doing more than one that's the killer.

I am doing this in the beginning:

```
CREATE TABLE #City 
     ( Order_ID INT
     , City_ID  VARCHAR(100)
     , FirstCitySearchText VARCHAR(100) NULL
     , LastCitySearchText VARCHAR(100)  NULL
     , OnlyCitySearchText VARCHAR(100)  NULL
       PRIMARY KEY (Order_ID, City_ID)
     )

INSERT INTO #City
SELECT i.listpos
     , i.quotedtext
     , NULL
     , NULL
     , NULL
  FROM opiscommon.dbo.SplitCommaSeparatedList(@City_IDs) i

UPDATE c
   SET c.FirstCitySearchText = '%'  + CAST(c.City_ID AS VARCHAR)+ ',%'
     , c.LastCitySearchText = '%,' + CAST(c.City_ID AS VARCHAR) + '%'
     , c.OnlyCitySearchText = '%,'  + CAST(c.City_ID AS VARCHAR) + ',%'
  FROM #City c
```

Comment: You should think about data normalization first. Show sample data

Comment: I thought of separating out the comma lists for each customer but I'm searching through millions of records at a time and customers that have 30 , 50+ cities in their lists.  I would like to find another if possible.

And because of the sensitive nature of our data, I don't know what I'll be able to put up.  But I will try.

Comment: That's not an issue. In fact, it would run faster if the data was normalized than what you are trying to do now.

Comment: Everyone here is correct - stop worrying about how many rows you might have to store / search, you need to think about how SQL Server works most efficiently, and when those rows are indexed it works MUCH, MUCH better than parsing comma-separated strings, *trust me*. Also, [please don't use variable types like `varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: This issue is that I can't predict what numbers they will pass in and I have to create a stored procedure to handle this.  This is not a one off request.  I get that I will have to use like, that's why I made the temp table the way that I did.  It's using the methods that the 2 who answered below gave with whatever and how many numbers they pass into the stored procedure.

Comment: So if I'm to use a tvp how would I do it.  The customer isn't going to pass in a table...

So then who would you do it?

Comment: How is the customer passing in a list of strings to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing instead that solved my issue was joining the table in like this:

```
JOIN #CityIDs c
  ON cpcpp.CUST_PROD_PARM_VAL LIKE '' + c.FirstCitySearchText + ''
  OR cpcpp.CUST_PROD_PARM_VAL LIKE '' + c.LastCitySearchText + ''
  OR cpcpp.CUST_PROD_PARM_VAL LIKE '' + c.OnlyCitySearchText + ''
  OR cpcpp.CUST_PROD_PARM_VAL LIKE '' + c.City_ID + ''
  OR cpcpp.CUST_PROD_PARM_VAL LIKE 'ALL'
```

And this what those search text fields are:

```
UPDATE c
   SET c.FirstCitySearchText = CAST(c.City_ID AS VARCHAR(100))+ ',%'
     , c.LastCitySearchText = '%,' + CAST(c.City_ID AS VARCHAR(100))
     , c.OnlyCitySearchText = '%,'  + CAST(c.City_ID AS VARCHAR(100)) + ',%'
  FROM #CityIDs c
```

I couldn't use the where clauses that were posted because I wasn't sure of how to join the table in to get the city ids, so instead I joined them using the where clause as the join.

This isn't a good solution but it's the only one that has worked so far.  I'm getting back the results that I expect and the stored procedure is only taking about 20 seconds to run, which is considered a win.

Comment: So how are you getting 20 city ids into `#CityIDs`?

Comment: We do so by the following when the stored procedure is called

    EXEC usp_ProcedureName @CityIDs = '22,900'

The city ids are passed to a VARCHAR when the stored procedure is called.  I then split the city ids with a function we created in house and insert them into the temp table.

You can see the splitting in the question portion.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.  You should understand how bad it is to store ids in lists, numeric values as strings, and foreign keys with no declared foreign key relationship.

But, when you are stuck, there are methods.  Here is a method using `like`:

```
where ',' + list + ',' like '%,22,%' or
      ',' + list + ',' like '%,900,%'
```

Comment: This will not work if they try to add 20 or more id's at a time, which is feasible.

Comment: @MacWilson08 Not sure what the problem is. If they are adding multiple values at once, use a TVP, now you can join to it instead of manually constructing individual like statements.

Comment: I cannot join the table with the city ids because there is not a field to join to any the other table.

Comment: @MacWilson08 Did you even look up what a TVP is? You join your table where `list` exists to the incoming TVP parameter, which acts like a table.

Comment: @MacWilson08 . . . This will work fine with 20+ ids.  The `where` clause gets longer, but the idea works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the logic for 22.  Repeat for all numbers

```
where city = '22'  -- exact match
or city like '22,%' -- first item in list
or city like '%,22,%'  -- middle of list
or city like '%,22' -- last item in list
```

Comment: This will not work if they try to add 20 or more id's at a time, which is feasible.

Comment: How is 20 or more not feasible with this solution?